# Opening WPF form as a dialog on button click

Tags: wpf, winforms, dialog

I am building a WPF application in which I need to open one of my WPF forms as a dialog (pop up) on the button click of another form. I know how do it in windows forms, just not getting how I'll do it in WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete explanation of how to do a Dialog in WPF:

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/wpf-dialogs-and-dialogresult/

The basic code you are looking for is as follows:

```
wpfDialog dialog = new wpfDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

The above article will walk you through how to get information back from the form if you want it as well.

Comment: wpfDialog is not working.. Am i missing any reference/ namespace..? Or is it custom class inheriting any dialog class??

Comment: @GirishK - wpfDialog is a dummy name.  You should replace it with the name of your WPF form you created for the dialog box.  See my link for examples and sample code.  It also references the MSDN documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var diag = new Dialog();
diag.Show(); // or diag.ShowDialog(); for a modal dialog. Returns a 'bool?'
```

`Dialog` is a class you have to create yourself, it should inherit from `Window`, which has the methods [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) and [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx). (In Visual Studio you best use the Window-template for window creation so the XAML markup file which belongs to the dialogue is created automatically)

You can of course create a dialogue on the fly as well. e.g.

```
var dialog = new Window();
var sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock(new Run("This is some text")));
var button = new Button();
button.Content = "OK";
button.Click += (s,e) => dialog.DialogResult = true;
sp.Children.Add(button);
dialog.Content = sp;
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

(*Code written right here, may have errors*)

Comment: Do I need to include any or namespaces, references ... i included Microsoft.Win32; but it is not supporting ".Show" method. Neither it is allowing to create me an instance. 

var diag = new System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Window.Dialog();
diag.Show();

Comment: `Dialog` is a class you have to write yourself, it's not in any namespace. You can just create a new window in the project, then you can create an instance of it and show it using the code.